# What does decrease-by-one algorithm mean?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I have an exam coming up and I've been doing some sample exams for revision.

I came across a question asking "Insertion sort is a decrease-by-one algorithm. Is this true?", and I have no idea. The basic knowledge I know about d-b-o algorithm is that the size of problem becomes smaller with every iteration.

Could I get more information on this? Thanks.

Comment: This is better suited for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) - which is for conceptual questions like yours.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes I did, but I still didn't understand it. Thanks.

Comment: @user2211574 Please include your research into the question so that we avoid reiterating what you've already found. What did you find and why didn't you understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insertion sort splits the set of elements to be sorted into two subsets: 1) already sorted, and 2) yet to be sorted. Elements from the 'yet to be sorted' subset are moved one-by-one into the 'already sorted' set. As the size of the problem is effectively the size of the 'yet to be sorted' set, it is decreased by one on each such occasion. The algorithm can thus be classified as 'decrease-by-one'.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort for more information about the algorithm, and http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4321/www/Lectures/Lecture%2010%20-%20Decrease%20and%20Conquer%20Sorts%20and%20Graph%20Searches.htm or http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc250/LN250_Levitin/L07-DecreaseConquer.htm#one about the 'decrease-by-one' concept.

Comment: Looking over the lecture notes in these links, I'm most satisfied with this answer.  Although I still don't fully understand the classification.  Does it simply imply that only one element is processed at a time?

Comment: In the case of insertion sort, yes, only one element is processed at a time, the one which is moved from the 'yet to be sorted' set to the 'already sorted' one. More general classifications include 'decrease by a constant factor', or 'variable-size decrease'.